# List of Wireless RSSI with JAVA on MAC OS X

Tags: java, macos, wifi, rssi

I am looking for an API to get a list of RSSI's wireless networks around my Mac, but couldn't find any yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [Core WLAN framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/_index.html).  Get [a CWInterface](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreWLAN/Reference/CWInterface_reference/translated_content/CWInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010960) given the "BSD name" of the interface with `initWithInterfaceName:`, use `scanForNetworksWithName:` or `scanForNetworksWithSSID:` without specifying a name or SSID (which will do a "broadcast scan), and then look at the [CWNetworks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreWLAN/Reference/CWNetwork_reference/translated_content/CWNetwork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010963) you get back and extract information such as the RSSI from them.

Hopefully there's some sort of bridge that lets you access that framework from Java; if not, you might have to create that bridge yourself.

Note that this is available only in Lion and later.

Comment: Do you know how could do that using Python to call this libraries, or using the Command Line Tool from Xcode?

Comment: Python?  I don't know of any Python wrappers for CoreWireless, so you'd probably have to write your own.  "Command Line Tool from Xcode"?  Which command-line tool?  "gcc"?  "clang"?

Comment: In xcode you have a way to develop Command Line Tool programs, but I am not able to use the imported Library

Comment: You can't just add the Core WLAN framework to your Xcode project?  (Framework, not library.)  Note that it's an Objective-C framework, so you'll somehow have to convince Xcode to let you build an Objective-C command-line tool.

Comment: I did that, but now I have to call the objects without using the Objective-C main types.... apparently it creates a C++ project

Comment: Yet another reason why I just use Traditional UN\*X Tools on OS X; Xcode apparently thinks it knows better than you do.  Try creating a "Command Line Tool" and, when it asks you for a "Type", select "Foundation".  (I guess they decided building an Objective-C program without using *any* system frameworks is pointless, so you have to at least build with Foundation.)

Comment: Not that easy! doing this way it fails to compile if I import the coreWlan package into the MAIN.C

Comment: main.c, not main.m?  Doesn't seem correct to me; the main source file should be Objective-C, not C.